# jsPsych: change button position and style

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspsych

I am trying to display two buttons using the jsPsych html-button-response plugin (https://www.jspsych.org/plugins/jspsych-html-button-response/). I am using images as buttons instead of text. I specified them in my "choices:" option as `choices: ["<img src='" + ButtonLeft+ "'>", "<img src='" + ButtonRight+ "'>"],`.

By default, the buttons show up centered and below my stimulus. Instead, I would like to display them ON TOP of my stimulus (which is in turn composed of a bunch of overlapping images - a background + some items), one on the LEFT and the other one on the RIGHT, in specific positions relative to my background. The default style for the buttons is:

```
 .jspsych-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

How can I display the buttons in the way that I am trying to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the button_html parameter did it!

```
button_html: ['<button class="jspsych-btn" style = "position:absolute; left:284.5px; top: 270px">%choice%</button>', '<button class="jspsych-btn" style = "position:absolute; right:284.5px; top: 270px">%choice%</button>']
```